# Custom UITableViewCell created using Storyboard shows no label data - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Problem: 
I have a simple UITableViewController and want to display a label in a custom made cell. I created a simple UITableViewController with number of sections 1 and rows 4 hardcoded. in storyboard, customised the cell with a new label, gave it an identifier and mapped an outlet in the DemoTableViewCell as well. Below are snapshots of all the different snippets of the code. Still for me the label text assigned in the function is not getting displayed.

```
class DemoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var demoLabel: UILabel!

}
```

---

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 4
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : DemoTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! DemoTableViewCell

    cell.demoLabel.text = "Override Label"
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
```

[image: Cell Reuse Identifier]

[image: Assigned a Custom Class]

[image: Outlet in the custom cell class]

[image: Output Screenshot]

[image: Storyboard Label]

Can someone please let me know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show your demoLabel in storyabord

Comment: Are UITableViewDataSource methods being called properly? Have to set tableView's dataSource and delegate?

Comment: Hello Just added a storyboard snap of how the Label looks.

Comment: Since it is UITableViewController class, I am not sure if we need to explicitly set the delegate and datasource. I am very new to Swift and IOS, so I might be wrong.

Comment: If I write the code as cell.textLabel?.text = "Override Label" it gets printed correctly. But it is not a custom label. It is the default cell label, which works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is **you did not set constraint for that label**, because your label is in center of the cell with custom height but in your simulator your cell height is only default height 44 pt

some option to do

1. you can try to set the **label to the top of the cell**
2. set tableview row height in storyboard to equal to your custom cell height
   [image]
3. the proper step to do is **set the label constraint** to make the cell height proper with the label position

Comment: Ok, that great, so apparently, that worked, the moment I gave couple of constraints to it. So, i will probably also need to set the cell height now, as I need to fit in an image and couple of labels vertically aligned to it. Many thanks for your quick response.

Comment: yeah, because with no constraint tableviewcell will have default height, if you want the cell height depends on the content dont set the row height, because if you set the height all cell will have same height

Answer (score 0):

Rest all of your code is fine except the autolayouts. You need to apply following constraints to your demoLabel:

[image]

[image]